# how can I break inheritance on a particular document/file in Sharepoint Library using MS flow?

Tags: flow, microsoft-flow

I made a flow which is triggered when file is created .I want to break inheritance on  document and clear all permissions from every user.

Comment: I just want to break inheritance on a single file (when file is created)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a 'Send Http Request to SharePoint' activity for a little more control of the outcome

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a step (Stop sharing an item or a file)

   a. select site address

   b. select library name

   c. provide ID

This step can break inheritance on a particular document or file in SharePoint library.

[image]